# How does the following statistics work?

Tags: estimation

How come a college could had 60 percent of 6 year graduation rate and total 14000 undergraduates accept 2500 new transfer student each year while the transfer out rate is 20 percent? Also, Does it mean a freshman in this college is almost nonexistent to graduate in the same college? I refer to baruch college.

Refernce 1: http://collegeapps.about.com/od/collegeprofiles/p/baruch-college-cuny.htm

2: https://www.cuny.edu/admissions/undergraduate/downloads/Admission-Profile-Transfer.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graduation rates are calculated based on first time in college students.  I believe that those who transfer in and those who transfer out are omitted from the calculation as are those who are not full time.  Of the 14,000 or so enrolled, only 74% of them are full time and many of the full time students are probably transfer students.

The transfer out rate is probably calculated out of all students including those who transferred in and those who are not full time.

The basic issue is that you're assuming a common denominator for all these statistics (the total number of students) but this is a mistake.

Grad rates are calculated out of those who didn't transfer in, didn't transfer out, and are enrolled full time.

The transfer out rate is probably calculated out of all students, possibly even including graduate students.

Students who transfer in don't get "rolled into" the calculation for the 6 year graduation rate either.  6 year graduation rates are probably not the best indicator of a school's ability to graduate students if the school has a huge number of students who transfer in or who use the school as a stepping stone and transfer out.  I speak from experience - I work at just such a school.

You can read more about graduation rates at the following link:
https://nces.ed.gov/fastfacts/display.asp?id=40

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what these statistics mean. If the 60% means that an incoming freshman has a 60% chance of graduating within 6 years, then 60% of incoming freshman will graduate from Baruch College. If you enter as a freshman, and have a 20% chance of transferring prior to graduation, and if you stick around, have a 60% of graduating in 6 years (I assume this is as opposed to having dropped out or needing more than 6 years), then an entering freshman has $80\% \times 60\%=48\%$ chance of having graduated from Baruch within 6 years. Your first question is not answerable. It is because it is.